# how to access the json array inside array from android

Tags: android, arrays, json

my array is

```
{
   newsitem [ 
              {"headline":"hello","caption":"date",

                  "image":{"photo":"img","thumb":"thumbnail"}
             }
            ]
}
```

I want to access photo and thumb using jsonobject and jsonarray. I am able to access headline and caption.

this is the code I am using to get headline. help me to get photo and thumb.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(retstring);
                JSONArray ja = obj.getJSONArray("NewsItem"); 

for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);


String h=jo.getString("HeadLine");

}
```

Comment: is it your full json data?

Answer (score 3):

You can try sample below :

```
  JSONObject new_jo = jo.getJSONObject("image");
  String pic = new_jo.getString("photo");
  String thumbnail = new_jo.getString("thumb");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. **image tag** is not `JsonArray`. It is `JsonObject`. So use this one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

  String headline =jo.getString("HeadLine");

  JSONObject jsonimage=jo.optJSONObject("image");


  String str_photo=jsonimage.optString("photo");

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`image` is `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray` so you can get `photo` and `thumb` values as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);

  String h=jo.getString("HeadLine");
  // get image JSONObject from jo
  JSONObject jsonimage=jo.optJSONObject("image");

  // get photo anf thumb values from jsonimage jsobobject
   String str_photo=jsonimage.optString(photo);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow these steps in order to parse the json
1) Create JSONObject for getting the result string.
2) Create JSONArray for getting array from "newsitem" tag
3) Create JSONObject for 
   3.1) headline tag
   3.2) caption tag
   3.3) image tag
4) Create again JSONObject for
   4.1) photo tag
   4.2) thumb tag


Now how to achieve this

 JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
 JSONArray newsItemObj=jsonObj.getJSONArray("newitem");

for(int i=0;i<newsItemObj.length();i++)
{
   String headline=newsItemObj.getString("headline");
   String caption=newsItemObj.getString("caption");

   JSONObject imageObject=newsItemObj.getJSONObject("image");

    String photo=imageObject.getString("photo");
    String thumb=imageObject.getString("thumb");

}
```